# Copy NSMutableArray and change it

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have method :

```
-(void)ModifyArray:(NSMutableArray)orginalArray
{
 NSMutableArray* copy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 copy = [orginalArray copy];
 Field* field = [copy objectAtIndex:0];
 [copy replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:field];
}
```

I get error in last line that prevent me from changing copy array.

When I use mutableCopy instead copy, I can change copy array but my orginalArray also change :/ I only want to create copy od orginalArray without references to it and chnage only thin new array.

Answer (score 3):

I see a few problems in here.

number 1 )

get rid of that first line, which is:

```
NSMutableArray* copy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

It's made useless by that second "`[originalArray copy];` line.

Use this instead:

```
NSMutableArray * copy = [originalArray mutableCopy];
```

or better yet:

```
NSMutableArray * myOriginalArrayCopy = [originalArray mutableCopy];
```

(see my last point in this answer)

number 2)

Your declaration needs a pointer:

```
-(void)modifyArray:(NSMutableArray *)orginalArray
```

(notice I also changed the first letter of "ModifyArray" to lower case? Best practice in Objective-C is that method names should start with lower case letters)

number 3)

Don't use "copy" as a name for a variable.  It looks bad (and it's probably a language keyword, too).

Are you even doing anything with that "copy" mutable array at the end of your "`modifyArray`" function?

Comment: Sorry about syntax - I wrote from memory ;)  When I use mutableCopy and use replaceObjectAtIndex I also change orginal array :/

Comment: Right now, it looks like your code is almost a NOOP. You take the Field object at position 0 and replace object 0 with that Field object. Whatever you're trying to do, it's not really clear from your question.

Comment: I am not show all code, I nil some of properties in Field  and then replace this object in array. MutableCopy copy also references to objects ?

Comment: You should make a copy of your "`Field`" object also, before modifying & replacing it.